# How did I get a folder with the name of dot "." in Recent list place?

Tags: nautilus, directory

I was looking in my "Recent" places in Nautilus and saw a folder named `.`.

[image: Dot folder]

My understanding is that a folder of the name `.` represents the current directory and is not an actual folder. I checked the properties of this folder:

[image: Dot properties]

There don't seem to be hidden characters in the name (like space-dot-space). The folder is in `/usr/local/bin` and has 4,728 items in it.

In fact `/usr/local/bin` has 16,512 items in it, so it can't be that (ie. the same folder as it is in).

If I open this folder by double-clicking it, it seems to be really `arduino-1.6.9` (ie. its name isn't really `.`).

[image: arduino-1.6.9 folder]

If I do `ls -la` of `/usr/local/bin` I see (amongst other things):

```
nick:/usr/local/bin$ ls -la
total 156928
drwxrwxr-x  7 root nick     4096 Oct  5 14:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root     4096 Apr 10  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x 11 nick nick     4096 May 10 19:18 arduino-1.6.9
```

---

**My question is**: how come the folder `/usr/local/bin/arduino-1.6.9` is showing up in the "Recent" list as `.`?

---

This is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit.

---

> Can you find the reference to /usr/local/bin there and tell us what it says ?

There seem to be a few entries along these lines:

```
  <bookmark href="file:///usr/local/bin/arduino-1.6.9/." added="2016-10-10T19:50:11Z" modified="2016-10-10T19:50:11Z" visited="2016-10-10T19:50:11Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="text/plain"/>
        <bookmark:groups>
          <bookmark:group>geany</bookmark:group>
        </bookmark:groups>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="geany" exec="&apos;geany %u&apos;" modified="2016-10-10T19:50:11Z" count="1"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
```

Comment: very curious question. I'd say it's a bug in nautilus. What about  `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` file ? That's where recently stored files are saved. Can you find the reference to `/usr/local/bin` there and tell us what it says ?

Comment: See amended question. If this is the offending entry, I would expect it (Nautilus) to drop the `/.` part and show the next level up.

Comment: it appears to be the entry, however it's supposed to only deal with files, not directories ( in other words, it is not supposed to drop the `/.` part )  More important question is why did it appear on the recent list, because it's not supposed to. It also shows that it came from `geany` IDE, so my guess is that you tried to open that folder in geany, and it reported it as recent file

Comment: Yes, I may well have opened that folder, but surely in Geany the folder would open in the open file dialog, and shown me the contents. Geany is a text editor, not a folder editor. I don't see how it is useful for Nautilus to say that `.` was a recent folder. You may as well say that of *every* folder.

Comment: When I double-click the folder named `.` in Nautilus, and I get `/usr/local/bin` then surely that is the name that should appear on the folder? (Or maybe just `bin`)

Comment: That's the point i am trying to make - Nautilus isn't supposed to have folders in the Recent list, only files. So there might be a bug either in Nautilus or in Geany

Comment: Or both? If app "foo" foolishly puts a folder into the recent *files* list, then Nautilus shouldn't show it?

Comment: Note that it can be useful for a text editor to open a folder; for example, vim produces a directory listing, and allows you to edit one or more of the files contained within it. (I'm not familiar with Geany specifically, but I think it is a valid thing for an editor to do, in general.)

Comment: Quite possibly, but I suggest that the "resolved" folder name should show in the Recent Places window. What use is it to see that "." is a recent file? That could be any directory on your system.

Comment: Look inside `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` like @serg said and make sure that it's not a symlink named something like `...` that goes to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: If there was, it wouldn't be named "." would it?

Comment: @Serg: you should convert that to an answer and ping me in chat afterwards.

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug with nautilus where nautilus automatically takes off the leading periods.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the problem here is a bug in Geany, which is responsible for populating your recent files list with the faulty entry. It should be using a 'real path' instead of a path with `.` in it when creating these entries.

https://github.com/geany/geany/blob/12b9f27a795f7ec8c1faf6c225314a09b6c5f7af/src/ui_utils.c

I can't see where your `.` filepath would have come from. I tried opening a file in Geany, and the new entry in `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` that appeared had the correct filename there, not a `.`. But if there is some use-case where you can open a directory in Geany, then that could be how you ended up with this entry in your recently-used file list. I would simply remove the whole chunk for the recently-used file list (or delete the file completely and restart, I can't imagine that would cause problems)

Comment: Yes, but Geany put the whole file name there as you can see from the quoted excerpt from the `recently-used.xbel`. The problem is not manifesting itself in Geany but in the Nautilus file browser.

Comment: I see the file name in your .xbel file as file:///usr/local/bin/arduino-1.6.9/.", so the final part of the pathname is '.', and that is what you are having rendered in Nautilus as the 'name' of the recent folder -- the last component of the path. This problem could be fixed in either Nautilus or Geany, but I tend to point the finger at Geany...

Comment: To show that Nautilus is capable of doing the right thing, I suggest removing the `/.` from the .xbel file and restarting Nautilus. I expect that the recent entry will then change to the expected behaviour, it will show up as `arduino-1.6.9`.

Comment: I can add, though, that it is expected that URIs can include 'dot-segments' so we can argue that Nautilus should be able to swallow them... https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.4

Comment: It's a bug in both programs, but Geany started it. Nautilus should be able to resolve paths with superfluous paths in them but it can't, which is also a bug.